# Как можно обратиться к элементам span содержащим скажем определенный текст с помощью css?

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, я могу как-то обращаться к элементам `span`, содержащим, скажем, определенный текст, с помощью CSS и установить для них определенные стили?

Например:

```
<span>Это красный фрукт</span> <!-- Красным шрифтом -->
<span>Что по белым полоскам зебры катится</span> <!-- Белым -->
<span>На светофоре свет зелёный пешеходам</span> <!-- Зелёным -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На чистом CSS - никак. Можно выставить только стиль для пустых элементов (`:empty`) и только [в CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#empty-pseudo).

Comment: спасибо, но жаль..

Comment: если не на голом css - то можно сделать через http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Answer (score 1):

Недавно был такой же вопрос, такое можно только в jQuery с его движком Sizzle через [это свойство](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83).
На чистом CSS это невозможно, да и, если подумать, это не его дело. CSS описывает правила отображения и ему фиолетово что именно в этих контейнерах.
Через JS можно выбрать все элементы и потом проверить их на наличие нужного текста - там уж можно развернуться даже с регулярками, что, конечно, куда лучше.

Comment: Спасибо! реализовал на js.
а, если еще нужно проделать то же самое, но для определенных разрешений экрана - как это реализовать?

Comment: пытаюсь подключать так - не срабатывает..
if (window.innerWidth < 600) {
  document.write('<script type="text/javascript">$('.entertain .counter_holder span.counter:contains("98")').css('top', '94px');</script>');
  document.write('<script type="text/javascript">$('.entertain .counter_holder span.counter:contains("37")').css('top', '181px');</script>');
  document.write('<script type="text/javascript">$('.entertain .counter_holder span.counter:contains("60")').css('top', '268px');</script>');
}